# Why would identityservicesd want to connect to a non-existent private network address?

Tags: network, catalina, macos

I saw a message from Little Snitch wherein `identityservicesd` has been trying to connect to a private network address that does not exist on my local area network. The IP address in question is: `172.20.10.1`

Any idea as to why this would happen?

Comment: Did you find any clues? I notice the same behavior, it constantly trying to connect to various IP addresses on the 10.x.x.x range.

Comment: No luck with this frustrating service @danielv...